# Return cells that start with string in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, google-sheets-formula

I would like a Google Sheet formula that returns any cell that starts with a string.

This is for a school timetabling system where the syntax is ClassCode(YearYear/SubjectSubject/ClassClassClass), room and then the teacher as follows
`08SC101 @ T201 (Valerie FRIZZLE` (Year 08 SCience class 101 taught by Valerie Frizzle).

The database is in a seperate sheet called `CLASSES` and each column is a single class period (Ie. `CLASSES!A:A` is Monday Period 1, `CLASSES!B:B` is Monday Period 2 etc.)

Let's suppose the database is as such for Monday Period 1 `CLASSES!A:A`

```
07HI101 @ B107 (Ashley HARRISON
07HI102 @ B108 (Emily CAREY
08SC101 @ T201 (Valerie FRIZZLE
08SC102 @ T202 (Lisa GRAY
```

I would like the output to be if the condition was class codes starting in '08' to be

```
08SC101 @ T201 (Valerie FRIZZLE
08SC102 @ T202 (Lisa GRAY
```

I have tried `=FILTER(CLASSES!A1:A99,ISNUMBER(SEARCH("08",CLASSES!A:A)))` for class codes that start with '08' however it is wildcard to the extent it also returns any cell that includes '08' that including rooms. The output would be

```
07HI102 @ B108 (Emily CAREY
08SC101 @ T201 (Valerie FRIZZLE
08SC102 @ T202 (Lisa GRAY
```

What other approaches are there to acheveing the correct result?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do some approach with REGEXMATCH also, but since you already wrote a SEARCH statement inside FILTER, you could use it to check if the result of SEARCH is 1 (meaning it's at the beginning):

```
=FILTER(CLASSES!A1:A99,SEARCH("08",CLASSES!A1:A99)=1)
```

Comment: Just tried this, it works! I cannot mark correct but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the LEFT function.

```
=FILTER(CLASSES!A1:A99,LEFT(CLASSES!A1:A99,2)="08")
```

Or with QUERY to avoid repeating the range.

```
=QUERY(CLASSES!A1:A99,"where A starts with '08'",)
```

```
=QUERY(CLASSES!A1:A99,"where A like '08%'",)
```

```
=QUERY(CLASSES!A1:A99,"where A matches '08.*'",)
```